# Ajax not function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, validation

I am trying to post the success function from an AJAX to release the validate function. It is working correctly because it is hitting my own API and I can see it is hitting the URL and the server is outputting a HTTP 200.

But I need my AJAX function to run in the same page and validate with alert.

**Script**

```
var $form = $('#formDiaDosPais');
var dados = {};
dados.Nome = $form.find("input[name='Nome']").val();
dados.Email = $form.find("input[name='Email']").val();
dados.Genero = genero;
dados.Origem = $form.find("input[name='Origem']").val();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'http://www.website.com.br/api/cadastroNewsletter',
    data: dados,
}).done(function () {
    alert('E-mail cadastrado');
}).fail(function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert('E-mail já está cadastrado');
})
```

**HTML**

```
<form id="formDiaDosPais" action="http://www.website.com.br/api/cadastroNewsletter" method="post">
    <!-- EMAIL -->
    <div>
        <input placeholder="Digite seu email aqui" type="text" name="Email" id="email" value="" tabindex="1" />
    </div>
    <!-- GENERO -->
    <div style="margin:18px 0 0 0; font-size:14px;" class="left">
        <input type="radio" name="Genero" id="gender_male" tabindex="2" value="masculino" checked="checked" />
        <label for="sexoid1">Homem</label>
        <input style="margin:0 0 0 5px;" type="radio" name="Genero" id="gender_female" tabindex="3" value="feminino" />
        <label for="sexoid2">Mulher</label>
    </div>
    <!-- ORIGEM E NOME -->
    <div style="margin:18px 0 0 0; font-size:13px;" class="right">
        <input type="hidden" name="Origem" value="Newsletter" />
        <input type="hidden" name="Nome" value="" />
        <!-- ORIGEM -->
        <input type="checkbox" value="Cadastrar" name="termos" id="chkterms" checked="checked" />
        <label for="chkterms">Li e aceito os <a href="http://www.centauro.com.br/sc/termosdeuso" target="_blank" class="link-termos">Termos</a>
        </label>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn right" value="Cadastrar" class="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: you need add reference to jquery before calling `$.ajax`

Comment: i have the last jquery version with reference:
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: where you add reference and where you add your code?

Comment: inside of my head tag

Comment: can you provide [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: I can't, I depend on internal codes to run this code

Comment: can you explain what the problem? any error in console, or what?

Comment: It has no error, the registration works properly, but I need to validate and deliver the message successfully without leaving the registration page. But AJAX is not doing it.

Comment: what you mean _AJAX is not doing it_? how you can validate?

Comment: The AJAX does not cause the code to run without leaving the same page

Comment: I need to run my validation without leaving the same page

Comment: Where are you making the AJAX call, then? You have the code, but when is it being attached to whenever the form is submitted (or button is pressed - whatever) and does attaching work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood correctly, what you have is a `submit` button, If you click it, it'll submit the form.

The fact that you've set up an ajax call somewhere in your code does not prevent the button from submitting it. You have to manually prevent the default behaviour of button and send and ajax request instead, something like

```
$("input[type='submit']").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault(); // prevent form submission
  var $form = $('#formDiaDosPais');
  var dados = {};
  dados.Nome = $form.find("input[name='Nome']").val();
  dados.Email = $form.find("input[name='Email']").val();
  dados.Genero = genero;
  dados.Origem = $form.find("input[name='Origem']").val();
  $.ajax({ // send ajax instead
     type: "POST",
     url: 'http://www.website.com.br/api/cadastroNewsletter',
     data: dados,
     }).done(function () {
          alert('E-mail cadastrado');
     }).fail(function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          alert('E-mail já está cadastrado');
  })

})
```